# How to add or remove a row to bounded datagridview programmatically in C# .Net Win App

Tags: c#

I have datagrid with datbounded with Add button, Removebuttton  in each row if i click on Add button new row should be added and when clickng on remove button row should be removed

Answer (score 0):

What kind of datasource you have? 
Id DataTable or something that implements IBindingSource then work with add/remove functions of your datasource.

Comment: Thanks for intrest in replying to me
i have set the datatable as datasource